# shinyBS Modal within checkbox group

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I use `shinyBS::bsModal()` to place explanations of the UI elements there. It works great when I place a `bsButton()` behind the title of the checkbox.

Now I want to place it behind the checkbox options.
A first hint could be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36670065/tooltip-in-shiny-ui-for-help-text/36696224#36696224) where the same for a tooltip is done (but my modification do not work).

Minimal Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("qualdim",  
                         tags$span("Chekboxoptions",   
                             bsButton("modalbt", "?", style = "inverse", size = "extra-small")),

                         c("Option_1" = "Option_1", 
                           "Option_2" = "Option_2"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      bsModal("modalExample", "Modal", "modalbt", size = "large",
           verbatimTextOutput("helptext")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$helptext <- renderText({"I can trigger a shinyBS::bsModal() from here, but I want to place two buttons behind `Option_1` and     `Option_2`" })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bsModal` works anywhere and just takes the button id as a trigger. So the only thing you need to do is to get a suitable button inside the `checkboxGroup`. From the previous Question/Answer you linked, you already have the function to get a `bsButton` inside the group input. (Just erase the line where the tooltip has been assigned. This is not needed here.)

The code below basically is copy paste now. I just added some extra `bsButton` settings like size, style and id (**this one is important! was not important in the linked question with the tooltips!**), such that you can use the function more like you would use `bsButton`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

makeCheckboxButton <- function(checkboxValue, buttonId, buttonLabel, size = "default", style = "default"){
    size <- switch(size, `extra-small` = "btn-xs", small = "btn-sm", 
        large = "btn-lg", "default")
    style <- paste0("btn-", style)

    tags$script(HTML(paste0("
          $(document).ready(function() {
            var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for(var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++){
              var input = inputElements[i];

              if(input.getAttribute('value') == '", checkboxValue, "'){

                var button = document.createElement('button');
                button.setAttribute('id', '", buttonId, "');
                button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                button.setAttribute('class', '", paste("btn action-button", style , size), "');
                button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('", buttonLabel, "'));

                input.parentElement.parentElement.appendChild(button);
             };
            }
          });
        ")))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("qualdim", label = "Chekboxoptions", choices = c("Option_1", "Option_2")),
      makeCheckboxButton("Option_1", "modalbt", "?", size = "extra-small", style = "inverse")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      bsModal("modalExample", "Modal", "modalbt", size = "large",
           verbatimTextOutput("helptext")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$helptext <- renderText({"I can trigger a shinyBS::bsModal() from here, but I want to place two buttons behind `Option_1` and     `Option_2`" })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```